# Real-time audio, temporary buffers in fast loop, different methods

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

My application must process real-time audio and for this I have to create a temporary buffer that holds the processed audio until it takes its way to the driver. I do this with multithreading so I basicly do:

```
float *ProcessChunk(int sf)
{
  float tmp = new float[sf]; // Remember to delete[]
  for (int s=0; s<sf; ++s)
    tmp[s] = myProcessor->Tick(); // an external class that does the audio processing and returns the result per sample
}

void AudioCallbackFunction(void *outputBuffer, int sampleFrames)
{
  float *out = (float*)outputBuffer;

  auto t1 = async(launch::async, &ProcessChunk, sampleFrames);
  float *b = t1.get();

  for (int s=0; s<sampleFrames; ++s)
  {
    *out++ = b[s];
  }

  delete[] b;
}
```

In the above example, which is perfectly working, every time a `ProcessChunk()` is called, a new float buffer is created and is then deleted in `AudioCallbackFunction()`.

An alternative method is to use a vector:

```
vector<float> ProcessChunk(int sf)
{
  vector<float> tmp;
  for (int s=0; s<sf; ++s)
    tmp[s] = myProcessor->Tick();

  return tmp;
}

void AudioCallbackFunction(void *outputBuffer, int sampleFrames)
{
  float *out = (float*)outputBuffer;

  auto t1 = async(launch::async, &ProcessChunk, sampleFrames);
  vector<float> b = t1.get(); // get another copy of the vector?

  for (int s=0; s<sampleFrames; ++s)
  {
    *out++ = b[s];
  }
}
```

And another alternative method is to create the float buffer only once when the program starts and delete it when the program quits:

```
float *tmp;
// Once i know the exact value of sampleFrames
tmp = new float[sampleFrames];

float *ProcessChunk(int sf)
{
  for (int s=0; s<sf; ++s)
    tmp[s] = myProcessor->Tick();
}

void AudioCallbackFunction(void *outputBuffer, int sampleFrames)
{
  float *out = (float*)outputBuffer;

  auto t1 = async(launch::async, &ProcessChunk, sampleFrames);
  float *b = t1.get();

  for (int s=0; s<sampleFrames; ++s)
  {
    *out++ = b[s];
  }
}

// in main() when the program quits
delete[] tmp;
```

Please note that the above code is just an example, my actual code uses more than one thread and uses stereo audio. Using only one thread would make no sense to make it "multi-threading", so please don't comment on this.

Questions:

1. how fast is vector to allocate and deallocate?
2. how safe is continuously create then delete a memory buffer in a very fast loop?
3. which method you think is safer?

Comment: `vector<float> b = t1.get();` what about reference or pointer? Do you really need another copy?
2. should be perfectly safe as long as threads aren't fighting each other.
The fastest should be the third one... but i would go with the first one (my personal prerference)

Answer (score 1):

1. fast enough. The memory allocated by vector for elements is contiguous.
2. It is not really a safety issue on a general purpose hardware, because you don't expect the memory to run out. If you are implementing a driver or this code need to run in an embedded system, it may be different.
3. The safest method would be the vector one, assuming you did it correctly (`ProcessChunk` doesn't resize the vector).

   Method 1 is fine, but you are still manually managing the memory. What if you dont *remember to delete[]* ?

   Using a `global` buffer require an additional attention to thread safety. How much depends on your real code.

You may combine vector and unique buffer:

```
vector<float> permbuffer; 

void ProcessChunk(vector<float>& perm, int sf)
{
  //perm size will eventually converge.
  perm.resize(sf);
  for (int s=0; s<sf; ++s)
    perm[s] = myProcessor->Tick();

  return; //good practice would be to return effectively read
}

void AudioCallbackFunction(void *outputBuffer, int sampleFrames)
{
  float *out = (float*)outputBuffer;

  //ditch async for thread to use references
  std::thread t(ProcessChunk, std::ref(permbuffer), sampleFrames);
  t.wait();

  for (int s=0; s<sampleFrames; ++s)
  {
    *out++ = permbuffer[s];
  }
}
```

Comment: You should never do any blocking operations on the main thread!!!! http://atastypixel.com/blog/four-common-mistakes-in-audio-development/